# Trying to find the best method

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, append

I will set up a register page using MSSQL.

The system must work like:

1. User appends data at something.com/register.php
2. The data is sent to host-ip-address/regsecond.php which my database will be at. (For security reasons, this php page wont directly access to the database.
3. The php page at host will start another PHP page or EXE file will directly reach database directly and securely.

As my php level is not high, I wanted to learn If i could start php scripts which will work and do their job without coming into users browsers. Here I explain what I say:

" I append some data at x.php, and it starts another PHP script which will do the job with the DATA appended from x.php but the -another PHP script- wont come into users browser "

I was hopefully clear ,as summary, should I use exe [will be harder] or can I start PHP script without coming into browser. And how of course.

Comment: Invoking another PHP script via an HTTP request, even if it's internally triggered, means that the script is also requestable from OUTSIDE of your server, so you've accomplish basically nothing in the way of security, except made your system more complex. And complex systems are easier to break than simple ones.

Comment: Not actually, the php script at localhost can only be called by localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the curl extension. You can find info on it here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

You can do something like the following:

```
$postdata = array(
    'item1' => 'data'
);

$ch = curl_init("http://host-ip-address/regsecond.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This makes a call directly from your first script to your second script without exposing anything to the user. On the far side, the data will come in as regular post data ($_POST).

Comment: Thanks, this was the exact thing i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't post data through PHP to a different website.

If you would like your website then you can configure your PHP script to connect to a different server for your MySQL, I wouldn't say it's a huge amount safer. For example
Instead of:

```
mysql_connect(localhost,username,password);
```

Try this

```
mysql_connect(http://your-ip:portnumber,username,password);
```

Comment: Mssql part is already done but it should be called by localhost for security reasons, anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem,  hope you find your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this correctly but you may

§1 use a "public" php script that invokes a private one:

```
<?php
//public register script
//now call private
//store data to txt-file or similar..
require('/path/outside/www-data/script_that_processes_further.php');
```

§2 request a script at another server,

```
<?php
file_get_contents('http://asdf.aspx?firstname=' . $theFirstName); //simplistic
//other options would be curl, xml/soap or whatever.
```

§1 may be used with §2.

regards,
/t

Comment: Thanks but this is not the thing im trying to make exactly. If you read next answer you will get my question.